# Can a defined provider that is a fat arrow method call another provided fat arrow method?

Tags: angular, provider, ng-modules

Lets say i have 2 fat arrow methods defined in the `providers` array of `@NgModule`. They are called `capitalize` and `capitalizeCallingMethod`.

```
@NgModule({
providers: [
    { provide: 'capitalize', 
       useValue: (stringToCapitalize : string) => { 
       if(stringToCapitalize && stringToCapitalize.length > 1)
         return stringToCapitalize.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + stringToCapitalize.slice(1).toLowerCase();
       else 
         return stringToCapitalize;
       } 
    },
    { provide: 'capitalizeCallingMethod', 
       useValue: aString => {
           return capitalize(aString); //How do i call capitalize?
       } 
    }
  ]
});
```

Is it possible to call `capitalize` from within `capitalizeCallingMethod` and if so, how do i achieve this? I've already looked at similar questions on stackoverflow about providers calling providers but they are all about provider classes that use other provider classes.

Comment: @Drenai is this better?

Answer (score 0):

For the `capitalizeCallingMethod` provider, replace `useValue` with `useFactory`, and pass the `capitalize` token as a dependency

An example of the format looks like

```
{ 
    provide: HeroService,
    useFactory: heroServiceFactory,
    deps: [Logger, UserService]
  };
```

- https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#interfaces-and-dependency-injection

Comment: this requires creating an extra class. The question is whether its possible to call a fat arrow function from another fat arrow function.